# Android: How to multi-select images through intent?

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I searched the Internet for quite a while without finding a solution.
I want to let the user pick images of his gallery using an intent.
For this i use a `GET_CONTENT` intent:

```
Intent intentBrowseFiles = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intentBrowseFiles.setType("image/*");
intentBrowseFiles.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intentBrowseFiles,1);
```

But this only works for one image. Is there any possibility to make it work for more than one, or do I have to rebuild my own gallery for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation clearly says:

> Output: The URI of **the item** that was picked. This must be a content: URI so that any receiver can access it. (emphasis mine)

So, no, there doesn't seem to be a way to use the default Intents to select multiple items. Having an "add more" button should be easier than developing your own gallery, though.